# Adding extension to multiple files in linux commandline

Tags: command-line, file-rename

I have multiple files in my directory that start with split4_, I want to add a .csv extension to all these files.

I am trying the following command.

```
mv split4_* *.csv
```

It doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps this question could be asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for file in *; do echo mv -- "$split4" "$split4.csv";
```